# Disposing of observables in dynamically instantiated Angular2 services

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 service which is instantiated once for each user session--specified as a provider at the top-level user component. That service creates an observable which drives some background processing for that particular user.

Will this leak memory? Is there some way to know when the instantiated service is "done" so that I can dispose of the observable? Do I need to do that?

Here is some sample code:

```
export class UserAppModel {

  constructor(
    private requestQueue: RequestQueue
  ) {
    Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      this.requestQueue.enqueue(aRequest);
    });

}
```

In other words, while the user session is in progress, I want to enqueue a particular request once per second.

This `UserAppModel` is "provided" in the top-level logged-in (session) page as

```
@Component...
  providers: [UserAppModel]
)
export class SessionFrontPageComponent {
}
```

So as you see this stream is not being consumed by components which can unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy`. I guess another way of asking the question is, is the `UserAppModel` which is instantiated upon being listed in `providers` in that component, then somehow destroyed when that component is "left"? Even if it is, how do I know that so that I can dispose of the observable stream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are basically two scenarios:

1. You use the observable data only in templates, by using the `async` pipe. In that case, Angular handles subscriptions and will unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. Nothing to do here.
2. You subscribe manually in your code, by calling `subscribe` method on that observable. In that case you should unsubscribe manually when the component is destroyed.

To manually unsubscribe, use the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook:

```
import {OnDestroy} from '@angular/core'
@Component({...})
class MyComponent implements OnDestory {
  // Component's code
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.subscription = myService.getData().subscribe(data => {...});
  }


  // Unsubscribe when the component is destroyed to avoid leaks.
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

In some cases you can get away with not unsubscribing from observables when they trigger the `finish` signal by themselves, but since it's usually an asynchronous and you can't be sure it happens before your component is destroyed, it's better to handle it manually.

If you're interested whether your service's observable ends, you can use the `do` operator with three arguments.

```
@Injectable()
export default class TestService {
stream: Observable<number>;

constructor() {
    this.stream = Observable.interval(1000)
    .do(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('FINISH') // On finish, all subscriptions will be disposed automatically
    );
}
```

Same goes for `.subscribe`. You can use the third callback in your component to log when the stream ends.

**Update:**

> I guess another way of asking the question is, is the UserAppModel
>   which is instantiated upon being listed in providers in that
>   component, then somehow destroyed when that component is "left"?

Your service will still perform those operations every second. You can try `console.log` something in the subscription to see that happening. It's really just like setting a timeout in the plan JS. The function will live infinitely and will have an access to the services instance, preventing it from being garbage collected.

As a side note, I would argue that creating side effects by subscribing to observables is a role of components, not services. That's why they have lifecycle hooks in the first place. You could consider exposing only the observable from your service, and manage the subscription in your service. That way you won't have this problem with potential memory leaks.

```
export class UserAppModel {
  constructor(private requestQueue: RequestQueue) {}
  startFetchingData() {
      // As a bonus, if your requestQueue.enqueue is also an observable object,
      // you could just merge it together to even better control
      // the data (requests get cancelled when there's no active subscription)
      return Observable.interval(1000).mergeMap(() => {
          this.requestQueue.enqueue(aRequest);
      });
  }
}

class Component {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.userModel.startFetchingData().subscribe(data => {...})
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a bit more information to the question, so it would be great if you could take another look.

Comment: I've added my two cents in the update, but TL;DR version is: yes, it will still leak.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one of them per session(not sure how you define session but it's not that important) I don't see any possible leak.
You should be sure that there is only one,
and OnDestroy you can complete the observable(to close all subscribers).

Comment: What `OnDestroy` event are you referring to/

Comment: Good point. I think the best solution is to add dispose function on your service. and call it on destroy of the root component that instantiate it